# Maximizing the Distance Traveled by a Projectile by Applying Chain Rule to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm having some difficulty reconciling my understanding of the fundamental theorem of calculus with a particular problem from Stewart Calculus. The question asks what value of the angle of elevation $\alpha$ maximizes the total distance traveled by the projectile with a position at time $t$ given by the parametric equations $x=(v\cos{\alpha})t$, $y=(v\sin{\alpha})t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$, where $v$ is the initial speed of the projectile and $g$ is the gravitational constant. The projectile is launched at $t=0$ and necessarily returns to Earth at $t=\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g}$ (as can be shown by setting $y=0$ and solving for $t$). It follows that the arc length of the parabola traced out by the projectile (as a function of the chosen angle of elevation) is $$L(\alpha)=\int_0^\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}\,dt}=\int_0^\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g}{\sqrt{(v\cos{\alpha})^2+\left(v\sin{\alpha}-gt\right)^2}\,dt}=\int_0^\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g}{\sqrt{v^2\cos^2{\alpha}+v^2\sin^2{\alpha}-2vg(\sin{\alpha})t+g^2t^2}\,dt}=\int_0^\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g}{\sqrt{v^2-2vg(\sin{\alpha})t+g^2t^2}\,dt}$$ From here, I see two possible ways to determine the $\alpha$ value that maximizes this function. The first solves the integral directly by factoring out $g$ from the square root to produce $$L(\alpha)=\int_0^\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g}{\sqrt{(v\cos{\alpha})^2+\left(v\sin{\alpha}-gt\right)^2}\,dt}=\int_0^\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g}{{g}\sqrt{\left(t-\frac{v}{g}\sin{\alpha}\right)^2+\frac{v^2}{g^2}\cos^2{\alpha}}\,dt}$$ and then uses the identity$$\int{\sqrt{a^2+u^2}\,du}=\frac{u}{2}\sqrt{a^2+u^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\ln{\left(u+\sqrt{a^2+u^2}\right)}+C$$ to eventually express $L$ as $$L(\alpha)=\frac{v^2}{g}\sin{\alpha}+\frac{v^2}{2g}\cos^2{\alpha}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sin{\alpha}}{1-\sin{\alpha}}\right)}$$  At this point, $\frac{dL}{d\alpha}=\frac{v^2}{g}\cos{\alpha}\left[2-\sin{\alpha}\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sin{\alpha}}{1-\sin{\alpha}}\right)}\right]$ can be set equal to $0$ to determine the critical points of $L(\alpha)$ on the interval $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$, the only one being at $\alpha\approx56°$. According to the textbook solutions manual, this is the correct answer.

However, I also feel that it should be possible to take advantage of the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule to avoid having to find that nasty integral altogether. Since $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{g(x)}{f(t)\,dt}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(F(g(x))-F(a)\right)=f(g(x))\frac{d}{dx}g(x)$$ shouldn't it be that $$\frac{dL}{d\alpha}=\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_0^\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g}{\sqrt{v^2-2vg(\sin{\alpha})t+g^2t^2}\,dt}=\sqrt{v^2-2vg(\sin{\alpha})\left(\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g}\right)+g^2\left(\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g}\right)^2}\,\frac{d}{d\alpha}\left(\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g}\right)=\sqrt{v^2-4v^2\sin^2{\alpha}+g^2\left(\frac{4v^2\sin^2{\alpha}}{g^2}\right)}\,\left(\frac{2v\cos{\alpha}}{g}\right)=\sqrt{v^2}\,\frac{2v\cos{\alpha}}{g}=\frac{2v^2\cos{\alpha}}{g}$$ for which there is no critical value on the interval $0<\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think the mistake lies in $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{g(x)}{f(x)\,dt}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(F(g(x))-F(a)\right)=f(x)\frac{d}{dx}g(x).$$ I think you should replace $f(x)$ and $F(x)$ by $f(x,t)$ and $F(x,t)$ and I assume you meant to have $\frac{d}{dt}F(x,t) = f(x,t)$ but then why should you also have $\frac{d}{dx}F(x,t) = f(x,t)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing term in your application of the chain derivatives, The following expression should be used instead,

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^{g(x)}{f(x,t)dt}=f(x,g(x))\frac{d}{dx}g(x) + \int_a^{g(x)} \frac{d}{dx}f(x,t) dt $$

---

Added the explanation below answering the question in comments:

Let the antiderivative of $f(\alpha,t)$ be $F(\alpha,t)$, that is

$$\frac{dF(\alpha,t)}{dt}=f(\alpha,t)
$$
$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^{g(\alpha)}{f(\alpha,t)\,dt}=F(\alpha,g(\alpha))-F(\alpha,0)
$$
Take the derivative with respect to $\alpha$,
$$\frac{dI(\alpha)}{d\alpha}= \frac{dF(\alpha,g(\alpha))}{dg(\alpha)} \frac{dg(\alpha)}{d\alpha} + \frac{d}{d\alpha}[F(\alpha,g(\alpha)) - F(\alpha,0)]\tag{1}
$$
Recognize
$$\frac{dF(\alpha,g(\alpha))}{dg(\alpha)}=f(\alpha,g(\alpha))\tag{2}$$
$$\frac{d}{d\alpha}[F(\alpha,g(\alpha)) - F(\alpha,0)]=\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_0^{g(\alpha)}{f(\alpha,t)\,dt}=\int_0^{g(\alpha)}\frac{d}{d\alpha}{f(\alpha,t)\,dt}\tag{3}
$$
and substitute (2) and (3) into (1) to arrive at
$$\frac{dI(\alpha)}{d\alpha}= f(\alpha,g(\alpha)) \frac{dg(\alpha)}{d\alpha} + \int_0^{g(\alpha)}\frac{d}{d\alpha}{f(\alpha,t)\,dt}
$$

Comment: I see why the extra term is necessary; I had forgotten that the antiderivative of $f(\alpha,t)$, $F(\alpha,t)$, contained a factor of $\alpha$ so that $\frac{d}{d\alpha}(F(\alpha,g(\alpha))-F(\alpha,0))=f(\alpha,g(\alpha))\frac{d}{d\alpha}g(\alpha)-\frac{d}{d\alpha}F(\alpha,0)$. Would you mind explaining how $\frac{d}{d\alpha}F(\alpha,0)$ comes out to $\int_0^{g(\alpha)}{\frac{d}{d\alpha}f(\alpha,t)\,dt}$? I'm still a little confused on that point.

Comment: @RyanC - See the added explanation in the answer.

Comment: Thank you; I would not have been able to navigate that application of the chain rule correctly on my own! Why is it acceptable to take the derivative inside the integral in (3)? If I try to do the same with the hypothetical function $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2}{t\sin{x}}\,dt$$ I get $\frac{1}{2}x^4\cos{x}+2x^3\sin{x}$ when I integrate with respect to $t$ and then take the derivative with respect to $x$, but $\frac{1}{2}x^4\cos{x}$ when I take the derivative of the integrand with respect to $x$ before integrating (as the expression $$\int_0^{x^2}{\frac{d}{dx}(t\sin{x})}\,dt$$ would have me do.

Comment: Integrate first to get $\frac{1}{2}x^4\sin x$. Then take derivative to get $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}x^4\sin x\right)= \frac{1}{2}x^4\cos x + 2x^3\sin x$. It matches the result from the chain rule.

Comment: Right, I agree that integrating first and then taking the derivative to get $\frac{1}{2}x^4\cos{x}+2x^3\sin{x}$ is the correct process. But this shows that$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2}{t\sin{x}}\,dt\neq\int_0^{x^2}{\frac{d}{dx}(t\sin{x})}\,dt$$ so why can we write $$\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_0^{g(\alpha)}{f(\alpha,t)}\,dt=\int_0^{g(\alpha)}{\frac{d}{d\alpha}f(\alpha,t)}\,dt$$ for arbitrary $g(\alpha)$, $f(\alpha,t)$ as you've done in (3)?

Comment: The confusion may be due to subtle abuse of notation. In (1), the 1st term already took care of $g(\alpha)$ and 2nd term is only concerned with $f(\alpha,t)$. So, no need to worry about $g(\alpha)$ again in (3).

Comment: Holy hell. Thank you for your patience! If I understand correctly, the notational ambiguity begins in (1); the term $\frac{d}{d\alpha}[F(\alpha,g(\alpha))]$ in (1) comes from applying the chain rule when taking the derivative of $I(\alpha)$, but because of the nature of the chain rule this term effectively treats $g(\alpha)$ as a constant. In (3), we have to continue to consider $g(\alpha)$ in this way when we express $\frac{d}{d\alpha}[F(\alpha,g(\alpha)-F(\alpha,0)]$ as an integral. Then, with $g(\alpha)$ being treated as a constant, the second equality in (3) holds. Is this correct?

Comment: You're correct! The constant-term notion during the chain operation is implicit.

Comment: How do you get $\frac{d F(\alpha,g(\alpha))}{d g(\alpha)}\frac{d g(\alpha)}{d\alpha}$? Shouldn't it be $$\frac{ d F(\alpha,g(\alpha)}{d\color{red}{\boldsymbol{t}}}\frac{d g(\alpha)}{d\alpha}?$$ $g(\alpha)$ isn't independent of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following term and it'll be correct:

$\displaystyle \int_0^\frac{2v\sin{\alpha}}{g} [\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}{\sqrt{v^2-2vg(\sin{\alpha})t+g^2t^2}]~dt}$